# Emacs lisp - autocomplete bookmark names

Tags: emacs, elisp, bookmarks

I'm new to elisp. http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html#Interactive-Codes lists 'code characters' for interactive parameters, which AFAIK modifies the behaviour of the input mechanism when prompting the user for input (eg: if you specify that the input is a filename that exists, emacs' autocomplete functionality will look for file names that exists).

I'm trying to find a code for a bookmark name that already exists - ie: emacs will prompt the user for a bookmark name, and upon pressing tab emacs will show possible bookmark name completions.

Does such a code exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `completing-read` for that. You could write a function that prompts the user for a bookmark like so:

```
(defun my-function ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((bookmark (completing-read "Bookmark: " (bookmark-all-names))))
    ...))
```

If you prefer the prompting to be part of `interactive` (so that the result will be bound automatically to your function's arguments), you could use the following alternative:

```
(defun my-function (bookmark)
  (interactive (list (completing-read "Bookmark: " (bookmark-all-names))))
  ...)
```

For Emacs to find the function `bookmark-all-names` you also have to add the following line to your .emacs file:

```
(require 'bookmark)
```

Comment: That's most of the way there - do you know if there's some default list that emacs uses in order to store bookmarks?

Comment: That should be the list returned by `bookmark-all-names`. Could you please check the updated code above? I don't use bookmarks myself... What should happen if the list of bookmarks is empty?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - SO didn't notify me via email for some reason (??). I get the following error message: Symbol's function definition is void: bookmark-all-names. UPDATE: I think you need to have the bookmark list loaded into a buffer (M-x bookmark-bmenu-list)

Comment: That's because `bookmark-all-names` is not loaded by default. Add `(require 'bookmark)` to your .emacs file (I've updated my answer accordingly). Any luck with that?

Answer (score 1):

Function `bookmark-completing-read` is the standard way to complete a bookmark name.  You do *not* need the lower-level function `completing-read` for this.  Example:

```
    (bookmark-completing-read "Bookmark" bookmark-current-bookmark)
```

If you use [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then `bookmark-completing-read` accepts some optional arguments (similar to `completing-read`) that can help:

- `ALIST` -- an alist of bookmarks to choose from (instead of all bookmarks: `bookmark-alist`)
- `PRED` -- a predicate that filters the list of bookmark candidates
- `HIST` -- an input history list

There is also a non-strict version of the function, `bmkp-completing-read-lax`, which is useful if you want to accept a new bookmark name or complete against existing names.